# I deployed my app on Heroku but I don't see the images when I add an entry in my database. What would be the correct path?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I deployed my app on Heroku with an mLab database but I don't see the images. My app is available online here: https://evening-bayou-56962.herokuapp.com/

The src of my images is the following

```
<img class="header-img" src="https://evening-bayou-56962.herokuapp.com/uploads/aefd5767e35894a025bd6fac4f252d3d.jpg" alt="vincent-peillon">
```

In my backend, here is how I add an entry with an image :

```
router.post("/add", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  // On rename la photo dans le upload
  const data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
  // console.info(data);
  const extension = getExtension(req.file); // Voir en dessous
  const filename = req.file.filename + extension;
  const serverPictureName = "public/uploads/" + filename;
  const apiPictureName = "uploads/" + filename;
  fs.rename(req.file.path, serverPictureName, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("il y a une erreur", err);
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ img: "L'image n'a pas pu être sauvegardée" });
    }
    Deputy.findOne({ name: data.name }).then(deputy => {
      if (deputy) {
        return res.status(400).json({ name: "Ce député existe déjà" });
      } else {
        // Delete the @ to be saved in DB and better diplay in front
        console.log("data.twitter", data.twitter);
        while (data.twitter.charAt(0) === "@") {
          data.twitter = data.twitter.substr(1);
        }
        console.log("data.twitter", data.twitter);
        const newDeputy = new Deputy({
          firstName: data.firstName,
          surname: data.surname,
          name: data.firstName + " " + data.surname,
          mandateFrom: data.mandateFrom || "",
          mandateTo: data.mandateTo || "",
          group: data.group || "",
          party: data.party || "",
          twitter: data.twitter || "",
          picture: apiPictureName || "",
          slug: slug(data.name.toString())
        });
        newDeputy
          .save()
          .then(user => res.json(user))
          .catch(err => console.log("err", err));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This works perfectly locally.

Comment: If you visit [that image link](https://evening-bayou-56962.herokuapp.com/uploads/aefd5767e35894a025bd6fac4f252d3d.jpg), you get a webpage, not an image. I'd guess your fallback for push-state routing is too broad, it shouldn't cover static directories or API endpoints, but a [mcve] is required to find out.

Comment: can you check the filename of the image. If its first letter is uppercase or not?

Comment: Before deployment, the path to my image was like this : <img class="card-img-top" src="http://localhost:4000/uploads/04c33599e1332785e8c9d42d2dda9939.jpg" alt="karima-delli">

Comment: The first letter isn't an uppercase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't upload images on Heroku server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480058/cant-upload-images-on-heroku-server)